# Visual Studio Builds Xaml Files Every Run (Without Any Changes)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution in Visual Studio 2017. Currently the Android and UWP solutions are unloaded and are not being used. On occasion, Visual Studio decides it wants to build the Xamarin.iOS solution every time I run the project. What I mean by 'on occasion' is that once it does it once, it is extremely difficult to get it to not build every time I run. The usual process goes something like delete the bin/obj folders --> Clean Solution --> Rebuild Solution. Sometimes this fixes the constant building, most of the time it does not. Rebooting VS doesn't seem to work either.

If any files in my solution have changed, the build message that occurs when trying to run looks like this:

```
1> Project 'myApp.iOS' is not up to date. Missing output file 
'C:\pathToApp\myApp.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\myAppiOS.exe'.
1> ------ Build started: Project: myApp.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
```

And this is normal. It needs to rebuild when changes occur.

If VS is deciding it needs to build the app every time the project is run, keep in my mind this is without any changes being made, it looks like this:

```
1> Project 'myApp.iOS' is not up to date. Missing input file 
'c:\pathToApp\myapp.ios\obj\iphone\debug\myapp.ios.c_.dev.users.jtth.xamarin.appfoldername.myapp.app.xaml.g.cs'.
1> ------ Build started: Project: StixApp.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
```

Google isn't much help on this issue. It seems, or at least would appear to be, an issue with Xaml files, as I am only seeing this output with Xaml related files (xaml/xaml.cs). However, with that said, I have no idea why this issue is occurring. This is the only piece of info. VS spits out before the 'Build started' message.

A few additional pieces of information -

The App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="myApp.App">
  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Primary">#2196F3</Color>
            <Color x:Key="PrimaryDark">#1976D2</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
            <Color x:Key="LightBackgroundColor">#FAFAFA</Color>
            <Color x:Key="DarkBackgroundColor">#C0C0C0</Color>
            <Color x:Key="MediumGrayTextColor">#4d4d4d</Color>
            <Color x:Key="LightTextColor">#999999</Color>

            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The App.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace myApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static Connection CocoonConnection = new Connection();
        public static Settings AppSettings = new Settings();

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

The myApp.iOS.App.xaml.g (@ path: C:\Users\jtth\Xamarin\appFolderName\myApp\myApp.iOS\obj\iPhone\Debug)

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace myApp {


    [global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute(
       "C:\\Users\jtth\\Xamarin\\appFolderName\\myApp\\App.xaml")]
    public partial class App : global::Xamarin.Forms.Application {

        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute(
            "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(App));
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Please don't mark this as a duplicate of @Chris's post, "Visual Studio Builds Projects Every Time I Run" as that post is not related to, what I believe here is, a Xaml issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as one could tell- this error was a result of a Visual Studio installation that needed to be repaired and/or reinstalled all together entirely. Have not encountered this bug since re-installation.